# Static iframe tab application redirection

Tags: facebook, iframe, redirect, tabs

I'm using a static iframe tab application for an iframe. I coded a send friend invitation button, but they get to the static iframe tab application page instead of my Facebook page. How can I redirect them to my Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear which Facebook functionality you using to implement what you call *"send friend invitation button"*

If you speaking about [Send Button social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) (Facebook doesn't recommend using this for invitations) than you should be able to specify URL to send.

If you using [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) ([Application Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) are recommended way of sending invitations to friends), which is more likely, than you should be aware of some things:

- Application requests are not designed for Pages but for Applications on Facebook, Page isn't able to send requests to user, and user clicking/accepting request goes to Application.
- It is better for you not to use third party application for hosting Page Tabs unless you truly trust that party and you should consult with your company lawyer that you not violating [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) (which probably will be the case if you'll success with friends invitation from your static page and it'll be hosted by third party...).

Best solution to your problem (IMO) is hosting content of Page Tab on your own, creating application and configuring Page Tab URL pointing to your static page and Site URL pointing to landing page that will redirect users to your Facebook Page.